# Too much space between rows

Tags: tables

Was wondering if anyone could help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
       \large 
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
            Time & February 18 & February 19 \\
        \hline
            5:00 & & & \\
        \hline
            6:00 & & & \\
        \hline
            7:00 & Leave Windsor (if Brandon's worked schedule allows) & & \\
        \hline
            8:00 & & & \\
         \hline
            9:00 & & & \\
         \hline
            10:00 & & & \\
        \hline
            11:00 & & & \\
        \hline
            12:00 & & & \\
        \hline
            13:00 & & & \\
        \hline
            14:00 & & & \\
        \hline
            15:00 & & & \\
        \hline
            16:00 & & & \\
        \hline
            17:00 & & & \\
        \hline
            18:00 & & & \\
        \hline
            19:00 & & & \\
        \hline
            20:00 & & & \\
        \hline
            21:00 & & & \\
        \hline
            22:00 & & & \\
        \hline
            23:00 & & & \\
        \hline
            24:00 & & & \\
        \hline

        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable.

Comment: you have not shown a test that  lets anyone see the problem, by default that will make a table with the same line spacing as a paragraph of text at that font size.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that on here David

Comment: put `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}` at the top and `\end{document}` at the bottom and check that that shows the problem that you are asking about, if not add whatever other declarations you need to show the problem.

Comment: Just did but it messed up the code. Always unsure with this site how to format that properly

Comment: highlight the code then use control-k or the `{}` button (which indents it by 4 spaces)

Comment: Thank you David,

Comment: The problem is you set up a 3-column table, but then enter 4 columns per row (3 `&` per row).  Adding an extra `c` or `c|` to the specification `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}` makes it compile without error and removes the extra row space.  You need to decide if you want 3 or 4 columns, and follow the specification

Comment: It is creating an extra row in between each row, visible as there is no bar separation between them

Comment: Time + Feb 18 + Feb 19, each one is for each column making three columns I believe

Comment: My bad I see what you are saying. That fixed the problem. Thank you!

Comment: sorry deleted comment hadn't noticed that you got an error (hadn't run it:-) . If you get an error always ask about the error not the output. The output after (any) error is not intended to be usable, just possibly for debugging.

Answer (score 3):

The problem arises because of a compilation error.  The error arises because you specify 3 columns for the `tabular`, but then provide 4 columns worth of data for many of the rows (as witnessed by three instances of `&` per row).

The solution is to remove the extra `&` to match 3 data columns per row.  Then, the compilation error also disappears, and the output rows are not vertically oversized.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
       \large 
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
            Time & February 18 & February 19 \\
        \hline
            5:00 & & \\
        \hline
            6:00 & & \\
        \hline
            7:00 & Leave Windsor (if Brandon's worked schedule allows) & \\
        \hline
            8:00 & & \\
         \hline
            9:00 & & \\
         \hline
            10:00 & & \\
        \hline
            11:00 & & \\
        \hline
            12:00 & & \\
        \hline
            13:00 & & \\
        \hline
            14:00 & & \\
        \hline
            15:00 & & \\
        \hline
            16:00 & & \\
        \hline
            17:00 & & \\
        \hline
            18:00 & & \\
        \hline
            19:00 & & \\
        \hline
            20:00 & & \\
        \hline
            21:00 & & \\
        \hline
            22:00 & & \\
        \hline
            23:00 & & \\
        \hline
            24:00 & & \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]